# Making an entity rotate with the camera - Aframe

Tags: view, three.js, menu, camera, aframe

I'm attempting to make a rolodex menu in Aframe like this.

[image]

Here is the glitch so far https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fourth-kitten

I'm trying to get the entity to rotate into view with the camera

```
   AFRAME.registerComponent('rotate-with-camera', {
    tick: function (){
      console.log(this)
      if(this.el.sceneEl.camera){
        const {rotation} = this.el.sceneEl.camera.parent
        const containerRotation = this.el.getAttribute('rotation')
        this.el.setAttribute('rotation', {...containerRotation, z: containerRotation.y -= rotation._y * 360})
      }
    }
    })
```

However I can't get a nice smooth roll like this example and I'm confused as to the right maths to get it staying in front of the camera on roll up or roll down to make the next row animate into view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position it in front of the camera, then just use the **parent** - **child** DOM hierarchy:

```
<a-camera>
    <a-entity position="0 0 -3></a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

This way your menu will be in front of the camera, and will be rotating with the camera.

To access outer elements, you can move the container a bit when the camera is looking right - left

Glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~gabby-newsstand).